# Is it possible to add Crystal Reports 'sub-reports' programmatically?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, subreport

I need a report with different sets of test results in separated sections.
Can't find much info on this.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Please elaborate- you've not given us much to go on.

You can certainly add multiple subreports and use conditional formulae to show/hide each subreport. Does that help?